# search engine program in android

Tags: android

I started android programming just 3 weeks back. I want to implement quick search program. I want to create a text field and when I enter text in that and click search, it must display google results for that entered text. How do I do it? Please help me. I am new to programming. appending the query to the URL and stuff is what I read But its bouncing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, re-use what is already there.  Have a look at this -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html  You can write a search provider that uses the existing framework.

Then have a look at this -> developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's gonna help you : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Moreover, you gonna need intents in order to launch the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I did go thru your link before. I have written the program and am able to open the web page. But Am having problem in linking my query string to the web page.Whatever I type in the text field, on clicking search, I must get its results.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Right now we have no idea what you've tried or what error you're receiving.

Comment: I want to create a simple quick search box in short. whenever I type some query and say search, it must display the query results of google.